# Как проверить char* на соответствие?

Tags: c, сокет, c++

Есть:

```
char* input = "google.com";
//char* input = "192.168.1.1";
```

Нужно что-бы функция могла отличить DNS имя от IP.
Как реализовать. Через try {} catch {} пытаясь обработать входную строку при помощи gethostbyname() или inet_add()?
Или есть другой варианТ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try-catch не канают. Кто будет возбуждать эти самые try-catch?
Поэтому проще наверняка использовать gethostbyname, а затем проверять коды возврата. Ну, и коли хоти try-catch, то используйте throw для возбуждения исключения по кодам возврата ф-ций. Как вариант - да, использование inet_addr.
Пример использования gethostbyname есть на http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524(v=vs.85).aspx>MSDN.
Еще гляньте этот Не могу разобраться с получением IP по DNS имени! :(>вопрос и примеры кода к нему.

Comment: Ну да. Это C# заразил меня.
То есть попробовать так:
использую gethostbyname(), если возвращает "не-то", значит IP?

Comment: Надо анализировать возвращаемую структуру hostent. Читайте инфу по ссылке. Там все есть. Вкратце: даем DNS -> получаем IP. Даем IP -> тоже получаем IP.

Comment: Сначала я проверяю на разные варианты записи INADDRANY ("0.0.0.0" "255.255.255.255" "inaddr_any" "inaddrany" (оба nocase)), потом inet_addr() и в последнюю очередь gethostbyname(). Пока никто не жаловался.

Comment: Кстати, как насчет варианта использования regex.h ? Или boost::regex?

Comment: inet_aton не спасёт отца русской демократии? Ежели 0 вернёт - значит не ip-адрес на входе.

Comment: Пасип :)